# Passive to active voice

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

Thus, the design is constrained by the range of current production motorcycle, and will be compared using miles/kWh.

Convert the sentence from passive to active voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad sentence to begin with. You can't compare just one design, and it is difficult to imagine how a *design* might be expressed in mi/kWh.

So I'm going to assume that what is meant is that it is what is to be compared is the ranges of two motorcyles: a current production model and a new design. And to cast the whole in the active voice will require introducing an Agent who performs the comparison.

> The range of the current production motorcycle constrains the design, and we will compare the ranges using miles/kWh.

But speaking of a range *constraining* a design is not very good either. What is probably meant is something like:

> A constraint on the design is that its range should be at least equal to that of the current production model. We compare them in miles/kWh: *&c*

Comment: I think it's a bad *question*, but I certainly can't fault the answer!

Comment: @FumbleFingers When I see questions like this I generally blame it on OP's teacher, not OP, and try to provide something for lagniappe. Of course if it's a homework question and OP turns in either of my sentences they may get whacked ...

Comment: I find it hard to believe even the most incompetent teacher would present that as a homework question.I'd guess the boss told his office junior to smarten up some documentation, and *convert all passive constructions to active voice* (perhaps to make them more accessible, or maybe just the boss's foible).